# SSRS - Grouping multiple rows per page based on varchar column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to create an SSRS report that will display all timesheets per person, per accounting period (month) on a single page. However, I'm stuggling to work out how the result should be grouped. So far all I seem to be able to do is get one line to appear per specified user per page.

My T-SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT tblADSI.DisplayName AS FullName,
       ds.[Date of Work],
       ds.Hours,
       ds.[Description of Work],
       ds.Mileage,
       ds.Subsistence,
       ds.[Activity Code] AS CompanyRef,
       c.[Cost Center] AS DiaryClient,
       r.Role,
       c.Description AS Project,
       ds.[Accounting Period],
       ds.[Rechargeable Items]
FROM [Diary Sheets] ds
    LEFT JOIN Commissions c on c.[Commission Code] = ds.[Commission Code]
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Roles r on r.Commission = ds.[Commission Code] and r.EmployeeID = ds.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN [Accounting Period] ap ON ap.ID = ds.[Accounting Period ID]
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT displayName,
        EmployeeID FROM OpenQuery ( 
      ADSI,  
      'SELECT
        displayName,
        EmployeeID
      FROM  ''LDAP://example.domaincontroller.com/OU=Unit1,DC=domaincontroller,DC=com'' 
      WHERE objectCategory = ''person''
      AND objectClass =  ''User''
      ') AS tblADSI
      UNION
      SELECT displayName,
        EmployeeID
    FROM OpenQuery ( 
      ADSI,  
      'SELECT 
        displayName,
        EmployeeID
      FROM  ''example.domaincontroller.com/OU=Unit2,DC=domaincontroller,DC=com'' 
      WHERE objectCategory = ''person''
      AND objectClass =  ''User''
      ') AS tblADSI 
    ) AS tblADSI
   ON tblADSI.EmployeeID = ds.employeeID
WHERE c.[Commission Code] = 'Example Commission'
      AND ap.[Accounting Period] = 'Febuary 2015'
ORDER BY FullName, ds.[Date of Work], ds.[Activity Code]
```

An example output from the SQL would be.

```
-- Name         Date Of Work     Hours
   John Smith   01/02/2015       9
   John Smith   02/02/2015       10
   Jane Doe     01/02/2015       5
   Jane Doe     02/02/2015       5
   Mike Smith   01/02/2015       8
   Mike Smith   02/02/2015       9
```

So using the SQL above as my example I've built a report which should display per page every user (based on the commission parameter set by the users) within a particular commission. However, all that seems to be happening in the report is it shows one row (the most recent entry for the February accounting period) and nothing more. For example:

```
-- Name         Date Of Work     Hours
   John Smith   01/02/2015       9
   Jane Doe     01/02/2015       5
   Mike Smith   01/02/2015       8
```

I actually need it to show all diary sheets for the accounting period per user so in the report, using John Smith as the example, it would appear as so:

```
-- Name         Date Of Work     Hours
   John Smith   01/02/2015       9
   John Smith   02/02/2015       10
```

And so on and so forth for every other user on a new page.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? I've looked into and tried some SSRS grouping (which I suspect is the solution) but I'm completely at a loss. No matter what type of grouping I try it always comes out the same.

I've been writing SQL for a couple of years, but I'm relatively new to SSRS and my SSRS knowledge completely self taught so some of my terminology/formatting is probably incorrect.

Comment: on your tablix you are probably just grouping by FullName, add [Date of Work] to the grouping.

Comment: You could try setting the Page Breaks option of the Row Group properties to fit your needs (e.g. Between each instance of a group). Is that what you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding all columns from my SELECT statement as parent row groups on my tablix. Thanks mxix and NickyvV for your suggestions, much appreciated.